# how to validate multiple dynamic textboxes in winforms c++

Tags: winforms, validation, visual-c++

i have created a table/matrix based on the user's input (i.e. user enters "5" and "5", my program creates a 5x5 matrix using textboxes). i want them to accept only positive integers.. is there a way to just create an event handler function for all those textboxes??

also, the table must display the sum of each rows and columns so technically, my program will produce a 6x6 matrix based on the example i've mentioned.

is it possible to validate each textbox after they lose their focus without creating an event function for each of them?

thanks!!

Comment: What did you try so far? Show some code.

Comment: Just store the TextBox references in a `List<TextBox>` to keep track of them.  The sane way to go about it is to use a DataGridView instead.

Comment: did what Hans suggested.. I had the dynamic textboxes stored in a list then added an event that validates and sums up the values.. thanks for the comments by the way.. :D